# How do I mark whole branch of a tree structure modified when any of the elements on the branch change?

Tags: java, c#, wpf, javafx

I have a tree structure and would like to be able to mark (color for example) nodes starting from the modified node up to the root. Parent nodes should be marked modified if any of the child nodes are marked modified. When a child node goes back to unmodified state parent should be updated based on the state of that node and the state of other child nodes.

I tried:

- Checking all children's state when the state of a single child changes and notifying parent. That is inefficient but does not take up memory.
- Keeping count of modified children in the "parents" and keep it updated, which allowed me to avoid checking all children on single child state change. This works great for 1 level down.

Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Why do you have this question tagged with [tag:c#]/[tag:wpf] _and_ [tag:java]/[tag:javafx]?

Comment: I need a solution in either of those technologies. Even general idea would be great.

Comment: What's wrong with the second approach? When a child is modified, it notifies its parent, which notifies its parent, and so on until the root is reached. When a child "becomes unmodified" the same notification process happens again. And the parent would simply keep a count of modified children; if `count > 0` then it has modified children.

Comment: Wpf has routed events which bubble up the tree of controls. If this tree structure was a wpf treeview then you could use property change notification. Or. You could pass a reference for the parent into child nodes and they tell the parent when they are modified. That is used by a method to set the entire collection state and parent state.

Comment: @ Slaw, You are right. I used this approach in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a call to all children to check if they've been modified. Then in turn they make a call to their children, e.g.

```
public class Node
    {
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();

        private bool _modified = false;

        public bool HasBeenModified
        {
            get => _modified || Children.Any(c => c.HasBeenModified);
            set => _modified = value;
        }
    }
```

Altered to add a working example.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parentNode = new Node();
        var childNodeOne = new Node();
        var childNodeTwo = new Node();
        var childNodeOneOne = new Node();

        childNodeOne.Children.Add(childNodeOneOne);
        parentNode.Children.Add(childNodeOne);
        parentNode.Children.Add(childNodeTwo);

        // Check is currently not modified
        Console.WriteLine($"Check: {parentNode.HasBeenModified}");

        // Mark node 2 has modified and check again
        childNodeTwo.HasBeenModified = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Check: {parentNode.HasBeenModified}");

        // Unmark node 2 and make sure it's no longer modified
        childNodeTwo.HasBeenModified = false;
        Console.WriteLine($"Check: {parentNode.HasBeenModified}");

        // Mark the second level child node as modified and check parent is also showing as modified
        childNodeOneOne.HasBeenModified = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Check: {parentNode.HasBeenModified}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is a "brute force" solution :)